# Error con node js

Tags: nodejs

Tengo un error con NodeJS y no logro entender por qué y mucho menos cómo solucionarlo. Éste es el error espero puedan ayudarme:

> Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 10.0.0 (x64) and npm.

Estos son los comandos que ejecuto:

```
C:\Users\yeison.castiblanco>node -v v10.0.0

C:\Users\yeison.castiblanco>node hello.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:573
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\yeison.castiblanco\hello.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:571:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:497:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:719:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:228:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:575:3)
```

Comment: No entiendo ese log. ¿Me dices que la instrucción `node hello.js` te lanza ese error?.

Comment: gugadev, si así es.

Comment: puedes mostrar el contenido de hello.js ?

Comment: Parece ser que tu programa requiere el archivo C:\Users\yeison.castiblanco\hello.js', sin embargo, este archivo no existe. No creo que podamos responderte por que es requerido, seria bueno que mostraras el código que dispara este error y el directorio de tu proyecto, de esta forma, al menos podríamos inducir si es que el archivo se encuentra en otra parte.